# Genesis 16:12, donkey, ass, or just wild man?

Tags: genesis

In the translations on biblehub, many have Ishmael as a "wild-ass man" or "donkey of a man" or a "wild man". Even the old JPS has "wild-ass man".

How can I know which is correct as it seems important at present?  And I don't really know if I can rely on a Septuagint as a person has said it was only the first 5 books of the Torah and altered later for the rest?

Comment: Be glad it doesn't say "Texan"

Comment: " ... a person has said it was only the first 5 books of the Torah and altered later for the rest."  This person is rather ill-informed.    See [How was the Bible canon formalized](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/56186/33515)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operative word here in Gen 16:12 is פֶרֶא which means "wild donkey" or "wild ass".  Brown-Driver-Briggs lexicon offers the following definition:

> noun masculineJob 39:5 (masculine and feminine Jeremiah 2:24, but
>   feminine probably erroneous, compare KöSynt. 157 AlbrZAW xvi (1896),
>   68) wild ass (probably from swiftness); — ׳פ absolute Hosea 8:9 + (so
>   Jeremiah 2:24 Gi; van d. H. Baer מֶּרֶךְ), construct Genesis 16:12;
>   plural מְּרָאִים Jeremiah 14:6 +; — wild ass Jeremiah 14:6; Job 6:5;
>   Job 39:5; Isaiah 32:14; Psalm 104:11; ׳עַיִר פ Job 11:12 wild ass's
>   colt; אָדָם ׳פ Genesis 16:12 (J) a wild ass of a man (Ishmael as a
>   free nomad); figurative of wilfulness Hosea 8:9 (see I. בָּדַד); of
>   lust Jeremiah 2:24 (i.e. Israel's love of idolatry); of poor
>   desert-dwellers Job 24:5.

This word occurs 10 times in the OT and always means "wild donkey" or equivalent: Gen 16:12, Job 6:5, 11:12, 24:5, 39:5, Ps 104:11, Isa 32:14, Jer 2:24, 14:6, Hos 8:9.

For completeness, the LXX translates this word as ἄγροικος (agroikos) meaning "wild" or "untamed".

Comment: Is there a particular reason that the KJV only changed this word for this one time? Any language reason in Hebrew at all, or KJV references of ntes of translation?

Comment: All I can suggest is that the KJV (and its descendants) elected here to provide an interpretive translation rather than a straight translation.  There is no marginal note in the 1611 KJV edition about this.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting observation!

In KJV we read

> And he will be a **wild man**; his hand will be against every man, and
>   every man's hand against him; and he shall dwell in the presence of
>   all his brethren.

The English for `And he will be a wild` comes from

> פֶּרֶא
>
> pere'

which can be read in more detail in [H6501](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H6501&t=KJV).

The KJV translates H6501 (which appears 10x) in the following manner: wild ass (9x), wild (1x, in Genesis 16:12).

NLT mentions

> This son of yours will be a **wild man**,

According to Strong's Definition, KJV and NLT's take is backed up

> **פֶּרֶא pereʼ, peh'-reh; or פֶּרֶה pereh**; (Jeremiah 2:24), from H6500
>   in the **secondary sense of running wild**; the onager:—wild (ass).

If I use my portuguese bible BPT

> 12 Será como um **animal selvagem**, sempre em luta com os outros e os
>   outros em luta com ele. Mas conseguirá viver na presença de todos os
>   seus irmãos e vizinhos.»

It mentions "animal selvagem" (wild animal). Gesenius' Hebrew-Chaldee Lexicon also points to wild ass being the only viable take.

[image: Gesenius' Hebrew-Chaldee pere']

So, if any lack wisdom, ask God (James 1:5). That's what ended up doing and, in this case, I would go with wild man.

Comment: darn, thought I had something important in a study confirmed in a way, but it has to be "ass" for it to be so.  Nevermind, it seems no one has a secure answer as the above answer from Dottard offers the alternative view.

Comment: doesn't donkey = ass?

Answer (score 0):

And the Angel of Jehovah said to her, You have now conceived, and will bear a son, and you shall call his name Ishmael, because Jehovah has heard of your affliction. And he will be a wild ass of a man; his hand will be against everyone, and everyone’s hand, against him; and he will settle down opposite all his brothers. And she called the name of Jehovah who spoke to her, You are a God who reveals Himself, for she said, Do I even remain here after He has revealed Himself to me?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it does not answer the question as I already know there are different versions of the same text verses as mentioned.

Comment: cool. don't they all mean the same thing, give the same impression? It seems then it's just a matter of the most common, natural, or elegant English. I was curious what you mean that "it's important at present"? Do you mean personally, to you? Thanks

Comment: It's important biblically in a study.